# Rails help sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want the default sorting to be rating DESC, but I also have, some ajax sorting.

Here is my controller:

```
def konkurrance_oversigt
@konkurrencerb = Konkurrancer.order(sort_column + "" + sort_direction)
@titel = 'Gratis konkurrenceoversigt | Vinderhimlen.dk'
end
```

How should I set the default order, without removeing the ajax sorting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def sort_column
  Konkurrancer.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "rating"
end
```